# Navigation Bar pushes down view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

In my application I have a `UINavigationController`, and the first view controller in the `UINavigationController` is the home screen. The `UINavigationBar` in the home screen doesn't appear. I want to keep anavigation bar on another screen. I turned the navigation controller off, but when you click a button which sends a segue to another screen, the `UINavigationBar` slides down animated and it pushes down a view which makes the view move down even though in storyboard, I set a constraint that the view should be 50 px below the navigation bar. Is there any way to stop the navigation bar pushing down the view?

Comment: what is your specific constraint?

Comment: try looking at `edgesForExtendedLayout` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraint is probably set to the `topLayoutGuide`, rather than the top of the view. The top layout guide includes the `UINavigationBar` and Status Bar when present, but setting the constraint to the top of the view will not adjust for the `UINavigationBar` (or Status Bar, for that matter).